Error: [@formatjs/intl Error FORMAT_ERROR] Error formatting message: "portal.cookie.modal.content", using id as fallback
在Next.js中用React-Intl 国际化替换时报错：Error: [@formatjs/intl Error FORMAT_ERROR] Error formatting message: "test.modal.content", using id as fallback.
MessageID: test.modal.content
Default Message: undefined
Description: undefined
Locale: en-US
INVALID_TAG
已确认MessageID存在，
{
"test.modal.content": "This is <a href={url}>link</a>."
}

Looking forward to showcasing This is the link The link can be clicked to jump, the URL is available, and the console has no errors
